# Perl Hashes of Arrays and Some issues

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I currently have a csv file that looks like this:

```
a,b
a,d
a,f
c,h
c,d
```

So I saved these into a hash such that the key "a" is an array with "b,d,f" and the key "c" is an array with "h,d"... this is what I used for that:

```
while(<$fh>)
{
 chomp;
 my @row = split /,/;
 my $cat = shift @row;
 $category = $cat      if (!($cat eq $category))  ;
 push @{$hash{$category}}, @row;
}

close($fh);
```

Not sure about the efficiency but it seems to work when I do a Data Dump...

Now, the issue I'm having is this; I want to create a new file for each key, and in each of those files I want to print every element in the key, as such:

file "a" would look like this:

```
b
d
f

<end of file>
```

Any ideas? Everything I've tried isn't working, I'm not too familiar / experienced with hashes...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @ikegami just personal preference... it's how I like to say "create a new key if the first column changes". I'm sure there are more convenient ways of doing that but efficiency isn't something I'm worrying about yet

Comment: It doesn't create a new key. It just makes a useless copy. And who said anything about efficiency? (For others that might be reading, the comment was about `my $category = ...;` being a better way to write `my $cat = ...; if (!($cat eq $category)) { $category = $cat; }`. I deleted after showing by example.)

Comment: @andrejr: It's usually better for clarity to write `if not...` as `unless`, so your statement would become `$category = $cat unless $category eq $cat`

Comment: Many people hate `unless`. It's not usual to use it. Furthermore, it's completely unnecessary here. Not just because the whole statement is harmfully unneeded, but because it can be written `if $cat ne $category`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output process is very simple using the `each` iterator, which provides the key and value pair for the next hash element in a single call

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.csv';

my %data;

while (<$fh>) {
   chomp;
   my ($cat, $val) = split /,/;
   push @{ $data{$cat} }, $val;
}

while (my ($cat, $values) = each %data) {
   open my $out_fh, '>', $cat;
   print $out_fh "$_\n" for @$values;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %foos_by_cat;

{
   open(my $fh_in, '<', ...) or die $!;
   while (<$fh_in>) {
      chomp;
      my ($cat, $foo) = split /,/;
      push @{ $foos_by_cat{$cat} }, $foo;
   }
}

for my $cat (keys %foos_by_cat) {
   open(my $fh_out, '>', $cat) or die $!;
   for my $foo (@{ $foos_by_cat{$cat} }) {
      print($fh_out "$foo\n");
   }
}
```

I wrote the inner loop as I did to show the symmetry between reading and writing, but it can also be written as follows:

```
print($fh_out "$_\n") for @{ $foos_by_cat{$cat} };
```

Comment: Nice to see both approaches. One question though, Is there a benefit of having the first loop in lexical scope?

Comment: @jaypal: It avoids the need for an explicit `close $fh_in` as the file handle is closed implicitly when `$fh_in` goes out of scope. In my own answer I have just left it open for Perl to close when the program terminates.

Comment: @jaypal, Code structure. Separates the input logic from the output logic. There's no reason for the output code to have access to the variables used by the input code.

Comment: Most programs are more complex, and would use an actual sub.